# ContactsContract.DeletedContacts.CONTENT_URI does not show deleted contacts from some devices

Tags: java, android, android-contacts, samsung-mobile

I am using a content observer to track changes in contacts, and depending on that I check added/updated contacts through

```
ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI
```

with

```
ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTACT_LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP
```

and deleted contacts with

```
ContactsContract.DeletedContacts.CONTENT_URI
```

with

```
ContactsContract.DeletedContacts.CONTACT_DELETED_TIMESTAMP.
```

Everything is working fine on my huawei device (Added, updated or deleted), but on samsung devices, the added and updated are getting catched and tracked but a problem existed with the delete.

The delete has 2 cases:

- If the contact is deleted from multiple selection (main contacts page) it is being catched in content observer but not in the ContactsContract.DeletedContacts.CONTENT_URI query.
- If the contact is deleted in the details of the contact page, it is being catched in content observer and in the ContactsContract.DeletedContacts.CONTENT_URI query.

The problem only occured with me (till now) on 2 samsung devices but not on a huawei device.

If someone had a similiar problem before, please advice.

Comment: are you running your query from within your content observer? if so, try adding a delay for ~5 seconds. maybe you're just querying the table before the DB had a chance to log those deletions.

Comment: @marmor no i am not querying the table from the observer, i am actually waiting for the user to reopen the app either from background or from scratch to do the operations, i will test delete, wait sometime and then check  if it is inserted.

Comment: @marmor i tried deleting and waiting  for nearly 10 seconds, same issue, it did not show the deleted contact

Comment: Are you sure this problem cannot be recreated on a non-Samsung device?

Comment: @TaslimOseni I tested it on huawei and samsung devices, it only happened on the samsung ones